# Using ResultSet to update rows

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to update some rows using ResultSet. Basically the syntax works as the following:

```
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE");

    while (rs.next()) {
        rs.updateString("something", "something_else");
        rs.updateRow();
    }
```

This works fine with simple queries. However, the query I'm trying to execute contains `where` clause.

For example: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE LASTNAME = "A" AND FIRSTNAME = "B"`

One solution I can think of is to extract column values from resultset, and then add `if-else` statement.

For example:

```
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE");
    while (rs.next()) {
        String lastname = rs.getString("lastname");
        String firstname = rs.getString("firstname");
        if ("A".equals(lastname) && "B".equals(firstname)){
            rs.updateString("something", "something_else");
            rs.updateRow();
        }
    }
```

Is there anything else I can do to solve this issue?

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is. Updating a result set produced by a query with a where clause should work. Do you get an error? If so what is the error? If you don't get an error, then what exactly is the problem? Also specify which database and which driver (full versions) you are using.

Comment: `WHERE LASTNAME = "A"` is invalid (standard) SQL. String constants need to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL: `WHERE LASTNAME = 'A'`

Answer (score -1):

Try this code,

```
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE");
        while (uprs.next()) {
            String lastname = rs.getString("lastname");
            String firstname = rs.getString("firstname");
            if (lastname.equals("A") && firstname.equals("B")){
                rs.updateString("something", "something_else");
                rs.updateRow();
            }
```

Comment: This does exactly the same thing as the code in the question. But your code will fail with a NullPointerException if either `lastname` or `firstname` is null - which is something that would not happen with the original code